# jquery - get a set of matched dom elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a page with div elements everywhere.
What's the best way to get the div elements with a custom ID tag.
e.g. `<div rIndex="34">john</div>`, `<div rIndex="45">Chris</div>`

I'm using this function to look for div elements with rIndex attribute. And I want to put those div elements into an array so I can do further processing.

```
$("div").each(function(index){

      if($(this).attr("rindex"))   
      {   
     results[index] = $(this);   
      }   
});
alert(results[0])
```

But the alert message is returning me a function definition, not the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<div data-rIndex="34">john</div>
<div data-rIndex="45">Chris</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var results = [];
$("div[data-rIndex]").each(function(index){

  if($(this).data("rindex"))   
  {   
 results[index] = $(this);   
  }   
}); 
alert($(results[0]).html()); //should alert 'john'
```

I tidied your HTML up a bit, working demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/aerj4/

If you want an array of the divs, you could do this -

```
var results = [];
$("div[data-rIndex]").each(function(index){

  if($(this).data("rindex"))   
  {   
 results[index] = this;   
  }   
}); 
alert(results[0])//alerts [object HTMLDivElement]
```

Comment: Cool but I don't just want the value, I want to store the matched divs into an array. When I do an alert on the result, I don't get divs but anonymous functions

Comment: Why would you iterate through all the divs in the dom? You could select the divs that have the data-rIndex attribute and just iterate through them. $('div[data-rIndex]')

Answer (score 3):

Custom attributes are done like this (w3c) :

```
<div data-rIndex="34">john</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this jQuery selector:

```
$('div[rIndex]')
```

But, as a side note, can I suggest declaring the divs in this manner instead:

```
<div data-index="34"></div>
```

and then using this selector:

```
$('div[data-index]')
```

Then your code complies with html standards.

Answer (score 1):

The [Has Attribute](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) selector supports custom attributes:

```
alert($("div[rIndex]")[0]);
```

That said, Yoda is right: in this situation, you should prefer the [custom data attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) defined in HTML5:

```
<div data-rIndex="34">john</div>

alert($("div[data-rIndex]")[0]);
```